# Android how to set the background color for selected item in navigation drawer?

Tags: android

In My App i created Side Menu using Navigation Drawer.I need to change the menu list item background color based on clicking state.So i used `<selector>` to achieve this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:state_pressed="true" ><color android:color="@color/red"/></item>  
    <item android:state_focused="true"><color android:color="@color/yellow"/></item>
    <item android:state_activated="true"><color android:color="@color/green"/></item>
    <item><color android:color="#ddd"/></item>

</selector>
```

Above code was working fine. After clicking a item in navigation drawer background color is changing fine based on the above selector and also navigation drawer will be closed.

But My problem is if i open navigation drawer menu item background color goes to default. So i need to set the same background color for the menu item.

Then if i open the navigation drawer my menu item comes to default color.No Background color for an item.

**But i need to set the background color for a menu item based on the current activity.**

Background color disappear only when navigation drawer is closed.

Please help me.

Sorry for my poor english.

Thanks in advance.

### My Code:

```
package com.example.qh_test;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class TechPageActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        OnItemClickListener {

    private DrawerLayout drawerlayout;
    private ListView listview;
    private String[] menus;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerListener;

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {         
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

    }

    WebView webview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tech_page);
        drawerlayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
        drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerlayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);



            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };

        drawerlayout.setDrawerListener(drawerListener);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        menus = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tech_menus);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, menus));
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.homeWebView);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webview.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/");               


    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerListener.syncState();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tech_page, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (drawerListener.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerListener.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        selectItem(position);


        //SelectItem.get(position).setColor(getResources().getColor("your color")); 

        switch (position) {

        case 0:
            webview.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/");

            listview.setItemChecked(position, true);

            drawerlayout.closeDrawer(listview);

            break;
        case 1:
            webview.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/questions");
            listview.setItemChecked(position, true);
            drawerlayout.closeDrawers();
            break;
        case 2:
            webview.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered");
            listview.setItemChecked(position, true);
            drawerlayout.closeDrawers();
            break;

        }

    }

    public void selectItem(int position) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listview.setItemChecked(position, true);    

        setTitle(menus[position]);

    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call such a method in the onStart method of your activity (with ListView mDrawerList and your DrawerAdapter as mDrawerAdapter):

```
protected void selectItem(int position)
{
    if (mDrawerList != null) {
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerAdapter.setSelected(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Carsten.Thanks for ur answer.I tried the above code but not getting the solution.I updated my full code in my question. Can you please take a look and help me out.Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you don't set the selected item in your adapter - only in your listview

Answer (score 0):

check this sample custom navigation drawer

inside onclick

```
  SelectItem.get(position).setColor(getResources().getColor("your color"));
```

http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/

Comment: Hi @niko Peikrishvili Thanks for your answer.Can you please tell me how to use and where to put this code?Because my problem is background color was changing fine.But after navigation drawer closed background color goes to default again.I think we need to set the same background color when navigation drawer is opening again.But i don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

In your OnClickListener for NavigationDrawer menu call method setItemChecked(int position, true)

Comment: Hi Oleg Osipenko.Thanks for your answer.I tried putting setitemchecked.But not working for me.Can you please take a look for my code and help me.I updated my code in above my question.Thanks.